# Adding ListAdapter to Custom ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have created one ListView by defining **ListView lv=new ListView(this)** in one of my activity.I have a Array of Strings which i want to add to this listview.How can i define a list adapter for this listview? Anyone having any idea? Can we create ListView like this as i mentioned above.Because it will show error "Your activity must have a listview with id android.R.id.list.

Comment: [This link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define ListView in xml like this

```
<ListView 
 android:id="@android:id/list"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </ListView>
```

This would resolve your error message.

You can have a nice tutorial for ListView and ListActivity here.

[ListView & ListActivity](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#overview_listview)